# How to create dynamic images with links from database in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image

How to dynamically generate the below image tag with links from the database.Number of images should be the number of items in the database.

Can we use listview or repeater to achive this.If yes how ??

```
     <div class="social-icons_box">

       <div class="label_social">
         Get Social
       </div>
       <a href="www.youtube.com"><img src="images/youtube.jpg" /></a>
       <a href="www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.jpg" /></a>
       <a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebook.jpg" /></a>
       .
       .
       .
   </div>
```

The database structure of the image table is as follows

```
Image_Id      Image_Type    Image_File    Image_Location         Img_Url

 1             jpeg          youtube      images/youtube.jpg   www.youtube.com

 2             jpeg          facebook     images/fb.jpg          www.fb.com            

 3             jpeg          twitter      images/twter.jpg       www.twitter.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the repeater  Item template use  the code something like this

```
 <a href='<%# Eval("Img_Url")%'><img src='<%# Eval("Image_Location")%>' /></a>
```

Bind this repeter with the Datssource which returns the Image _URL and Image_Location columns

Answer (score 1):

```
  <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="DataList1" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                        <a id="avalue" runat="server" href='<%# Eval("Img_Url")%'> <asp:Image ID="lmgElementImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Bind("Image_Location") %>' Width="24px" Height="26px"></asp:Image></a>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:DataList>
```